# What to do when someone deliberately down-votes many of the questions which I have asked?

Tags: support, downvote-reason

Someone deliberately downvoted the questions which I have asked in the nearby past.

The reason is that I downvoted him on one of my [thread](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/40579/is-evolution-really-a-fact-and-not-just-a-theory) in ***biology.stackexchange.com***.

I came to know because I decently left a comment describing what was wrong with his answer. 
In fact his/her answer was removed from there as well.

[image]

Kindly suggest me what to do next?

Comment: If there was in fact serial dowovoting by someone, the autobot scripts should reverse it within the next 24 hours. You just need a little patieince and an understanding of how things work.